# How to toggle the visibility of a script tag?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, scripting, google-analytics

How do I toggle the visiblity of a

```
<script>
```

tag in the markup? Have the following javascript code in my master page:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try {
   var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-108xxxx-2");
   pageTracker._trackPageview();
  } catch (err) { }
</script>
</body>
```

What is the best approach to serverside block this script from being rendered, if I want it to (like running in debug mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it inside a server-side `if` block.

For example:

```
<% if (!Request.IsLocal) { %>
<script  type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try {
   var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-108xxxx-2");
   pageTracker._trackPageview();
  } catch (err) { }
</script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick to this one ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PHScripts" runat="server">
  <script  type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    try {
     var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-108xxxx-2");
     pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { }
  </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In your page:

```
PHScripts.Visible = !IsDebugMode;
```

For settings, I use a static class called AppSettings, and have a simple property like this beside the rest to determine if it's a debug build:

```
public static bool IsDebugMode
{
  get
  {
#if DEBUG
  return true;
#else
  return false;
#endif
  }
}
```

Then anywhere in the app:

```
AppSettings.IsDebugMode;
```

Comment: I think you meant `PHScripts.Visible = !IsDebugMode;`

Comment: @çağdaş - Fixed, thanks! I'm normally showing more on debug if anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One would be to add in a preprocessor directive, put your script in an external file and register the script from the code behind:

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if !DEBUG
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myScript", "/path/to/my/script.js");
#endif
}
```

The above assumes you moved your script to `/path/to/my/script.js` file....

Here's a good reference on the `#if` preprocessor directive and how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago but hey-ho...

Why not use an `<asp:Literal />` tag? As you can control the `Visible` state of this.

The bonus of this is that no extra content is rendered (doesn't mess up if you need a `<script>` in the `<head>` tag) and you don't have any inline code.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You might all be over complicating the problem.

Why not just and an ID and RunAt tag to the script:

```
<script id="DebugScript" runat="server">
var x = 1;
</script>
```

Then toggle it in the codebehind?

```
If bDebug Then
  DebugScript.visible = True
Else
  DebugScript.visible = False
End If
```

Comment: I tried this one first, but somehow I got compile errors with the script I posted above.

Comment: This is obvious solution at the first glance, but unfortunately `<script runat="server"` has different non-obvious behavior in ASP.NET (do not know why, it would be better if they did another tag instead)...